# Cannot find a common SQL that will work both for H2 and Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, h2

In my project, I am using Postgres database, but sometimes, for development, I am using H2.
I am trying to define an sql script which will update a timestamp column as described below, but I could not find a single format that can be applied both to Postgres and a to H2.

Basically, the sql is trying to set the timestamp to be `NOW + 1 week`.

Here is the sql that works for Postgres:

```
update mytable set mytime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '7 days';
```

Here is the sql that works for H2:

```
update mytable set mytime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 7;
```

Can someone suggest an single sql that can do the same for both databases?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a different DBMS for development in the first place. That is asking for trouble.

Comment: and apparently if you need deploy to customers who dictate their own database, well then you need to find new customers!

Comment: Tips for running Postgres in development: Postgres can be rather heavyweight install, so alternatively you can use [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) if on a Mac, or install a virtual machine such as VirualBox or Fusion or Parallels where you install Postgres on top of an OS such as BSD/Linux/macOS, or use Postgres-as-a-service from vendors such as Heroku or Amazon AWS or Azure, or run a virtual machine such as on Digital Ocean where you install Postgres on top of the FreeBSD or Linux instance they provide.

Answer (score 5):

According to my test, this works for both H2 and PostgreSQL:

```
update mytable set mytime = 
cast(cast(current_timestamp as date) + 7 as timestamp) + 
cast(current_timestamp as time);
```

It is a bit strange I agree, but it is the only way I found with current versions of H2 and PostgreSQL.

Comment: This seems to be ok for adding/subtracting days, how would you do it for hours? Is it even possible ?

Comment: I'm also struggling with a similar situation but with minutes now. Any updates on how to approach hours ?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue where we use PostgreSQL for our app, but our unit tests use H2. We ended up just moving the date arithmetic into the application code. So, using the example above, the sql was change to be

```
update mytable set mytime = ?;
```

And then in the application code (using Java) we figured out the time:

```
Instant future1Week = Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.WEEKS);
```

And bound that value in the PreparedStatement.